# What are the differences between accentColor and foregroundColor in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I don't know why there are both `accentColor` and `foregroundColor` properties in SwiftUI. I can't see their differences. For example:

```
Button(action: {}, label: {Text("Button")}).accentColor(.red)
Button(action: {}, label: {Text("Button")}).foregroundColor(.red)
```

The two buttons look the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both yield the same result when applied to a Button. However, you can retrieve the accent color of the current context more easily using `Color.accentColor` as described [here:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/accentcolor)

```
VStack(spacing: 20) {
    Text("Default Accent Color")
        .foregroundStyle(Color.accentColor)
    Group {
        Text("Overridden Accent Color")
            // will be red
            .foregroundStyle(Color.accentColor)
    }
    .accentColor(.red)
}
```

Comment: `foregroundStyle`? I have no such API. Do you mean `foregroundColor`?

Comment: @蘇哲聖 You can use either in this case. `foregroundStyle` is available from iOS 15 and up. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/foregroundstyle(_:)?changes=_2_8_2